# How to make a flex item not fill the height of the flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the code below, the left div inside the flex container stretches to meet the height of the right div. Is there an attribute I can set to make its height the minimum required for holding its content (like usual `height: auto` divs outside flex containers)?

```css
#a {
  display: flex;
}
#a > div {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
#b {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">left</div>
  <div>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 223, accepted):

The `align-items`, or respectively `align-content` attribute controls this behaviour.

`align-items` defines the items' positioning **perpendicularly** to `flex-direction`.

The default `flex-direction` is `row`, therfore vertical placement can be controlled with `align-items`.

There is also the `align-self` attribute to control the alignment on a per item basis.

```css
#a {
  display:flex;

  align-items:flex-start;
  align-content:flex-start;
  }

#a > div {
  
  background-color:red;
  padding:5px;
  margin:2px;
  }
 #a > #c {
  align-self:stretch;
 }
```

```html
<div id="a">
  
  <div id="b">left</div>
  <div id="c">middle</div>
  <div>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br></div>
  
</div>
```

css-tricks has an excellent [article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on the topic. **I recommend reading it a couple of times.**

Answer (score 75):

When you create a flex container various default flex rules come into play.

Two of these default rules are [`flex-direction: row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) and [`align-items: stretch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items). This means that flex items will automatically align in a single row, and each item will fill the height of the container.

If you don't want flex items to stretch – i.e., like you wrote:

> *make its height the minimum required for holding its content*

... then simply override the default with `align-items: flex-start`.

```css
#a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; /* NEW */
}
#a > div {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
#b {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">left</div>
  <div>
    right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Here's an illustration from the [flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property) that highlights the five values for `align-items` and how they position flex items within the container. As mentioned before, `stretch` is the default value.*

[image]
<sup>Source: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)</sup>