# Block growing height in MatExpansionPanel when in flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

In my case, if one of the expansion panel is open, other panels on left and right shouldn't grow vertically. How should I proceed to do this?

Here's the behaviour with Mat components: [StackBlitz (current)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x18edt?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html)

Here's the behaviour I would like (with example divs): [StackBlitz (expected)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egw5wm?file=app/grid-list-dynamic-example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw a simple solution came from [How to make a flex item not fill the height of the flex container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212892/how-to-make-a-flex-item-not-fill-the-height-of-the-flex-container)

It was solved using  `align-items: flex-start` on parent

Answer (score 1):

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x18edt-6pgjhj)

To achieve this, additional css properties need to be added to the containing `div` element:

```
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start;
align-content: flex-start;
```

Consider using the [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) module, as this provides an API for wrapping these classes.