# Fill vertical space with Flexbox in a list of items

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a list of items, each one in `display: flex` to position its children elements. The height of the item is given by the image, and the button at the right position should fill the vertical space of the item. But I can't do that.

```css
.Main-item {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.Main-img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.Main-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex: 1 1;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.Main-buttonWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 146px;
}

.Main-button {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="Main-item">
  <img class="Main-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="Main-name">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="Main-buttonWrapper"><button class="Main-button">button</button></div>
 </div>
 <div class="Main-item">
  <img class="Main-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="Main-name">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="Main-buttonWrapper"><button class="Main-button">button</button></div>
 </div>
 <div class="Main-item">
  <img class="Main-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="Main-name">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="Main-buttonWrapper"><button class="Main-button">button</button></div>
 </div>
 <div class="Main-item">
  <img class="Main-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="Main-name">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="Main-buttonWrapper"><button class="Main-button">button</button></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any idea will be welcome!

Comment: Your question is vague. "I have a list of items, each one in display: flex to position its children elements. This elements should fill the vertical space" -- which elements should fill the vertical space? The items of the list or the children elements of every item of the list?

Comment: @amn question edited. Probably is better explained now.

Comment: Just remove the `height: 100%` from `.Main-buttonWrapper`

Comment: @Yandy_Viera Thats it!

Comment: I must be missing something, because removing `height` rule from `.Main-buttonWrapper` doesn't make your button occupy item height.

Comment: I provide an answer to give you an idea of why it happens and not only how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a flex container various default flex rules come into play.

Two of these default rules are `flex-direction: row` and `align-items: stretch`. This means that flex items will automatically align in a single row, and each item will fill the height of the container.

If you change the value of `align-items` to for example `flex-start` it will change the default behavior 'stretch' as well if you set a specific height to the child of a flex container.

So just remove the `height: 100%` from `.Main-buttonWrapper` and it will have the default behavior.

For a better understanding look this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33220564/4966662

Answer (score 0):

I've given a height to the `Main-item` + `align-items:stretch;`. I hope this is what you need.

```
.Main-item {
    align-items:stretch;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```css
.Main-element {
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.Main-item {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    align-items:stretch;
    height: 50px;
}

.Main-img {
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.Main-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex: 1 1;
    padding: 0 10px;
}



.Main-buttonWrapper {
    width: 146px;
}

.Main-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main-element">
 <div class="Main-item">
  <img class="Main-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="Main-name">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="Main-buttonWrapper"><button class="Main-button">button</button></div>
 </div>
 <div class="Main-item">
  <img class="Main-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="Main-name">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="Main-buttonWrapper"><button class="Main-button">button</button></div>
 </div>
 <div class="Main-item">
  <img class="Main-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="Main-name">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="Main-buttonWrapper"><button class="Main-button">button</button></div>
 </div>
 <div class="Main-item">
  <img class="Main-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="Main-name">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="Main-buttonWrapper"><button class="Main-button">button</button></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta; what I'm trying to do is to make the button fill the vertical space, not to align it in the center.

Answer (score 0):

A flex item stretches along the container cross axis by default, so the only thing you need to make the button stretch visually as well, is to make the button container a flex container by adding `display: flex` to `.Main-buttonWrapper`.