# Aligning horizontally the text of 2 different elements (<p> and <a>)

Tags: css

The text inside `<p>` and `<a>` is not on the same horizontal line, why? I have tried with `display: inline-block` or `text-align` and it does not seem to work. How is it possible to change `<p>`'s text to make it on the same line of `<a>`'s text and the other way round? The only way I can think is changing the padding in a trial and error fashion. Is there any other more intelligent way?

```css
.down {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
}
#fright {
    background: rgb(220, 20, 60, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: end;
}

#fleft {
    background: rgb(220, 20, 60, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 14px 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#heart {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="down">
        <p id="fleft">Made with <span id="heart">♡</span> in Seattle</p>
        <a id="fright" href="#">Contact Me</a>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Did you want to retain the differing heights of the boxes?

Comment: No! Just have two boxes with the same height and the text of each of them on the same horizontal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two issues. `<p>` elements have default top and bottom margins, so you need to remove them with `#fleft { margin:0 }`

Second, the font-size of the heart is making the line heights of the two elements different. You can correct that by setting the line-height of the heart to 0.

```css
.down {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
}
#fright {
    background: rgb(220, 20, 60, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: end;
}

#fleft {
    background: rgb(220, 20, 60, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 14px 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 0;
}

#heart {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer class="down">
    <p id="fleft">Made with <span id="heart">♡</span> in Seattle</p>
    <a id="fright" href="#">Contact Me</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: This does not sole the problem. Try adding some more text in the paragaph.

Answer (score 0):

#### Flex

When you use, `display:flex;` , two default flex proeprties are applied with:

1. `flex-direction: row`
2. `align-items: stretch` - *Its content is strached. And the shortest (in terms of height) takes as much as space as available.*

You need to change its `align-items` so that its contents take as much space as they need. Use `align-items: center;` on `.down` to do so.

```css
.down {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  align-items: center;
  /* NEW */
}

#fright {
  background: rgb(220, 20, 60, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: end;
}

#fleft {
  background: rgb(220, 20, 60, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#heart {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 0; // NEW
}
```

```html
<footer class="down">
  <p id="fleft">Made with <span id="heart">♡</span> in Seattle</p>
  <a id="fright" href="#">Contact Me</a>
</footer>
```

---

Visit this question which is similar to yours. But not the same.

[How to make a flex item not fill the height of the flex container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212892/how-to-make-a-flex-item-not-fill-the-height-of-the-flex-container)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Unfortunately the text of the 2 elements is not alligned horizontally yet.

Comment: @Mette use `line-height: 0;` on `.heart`